# foldr vs foldl as reduce operator in APL

Tags: apl

In  Kenneth Iverson’s *A Programming Language* the reduction operation `op/` is defined as a *foldl* (left fold):

```
The ◌-reduction of a vector  is denoted by ◌/ and defined as
    z←◌/ ⟺ z = (⋯((₁ ◌ ₂) ◌ ₃) ◌ ⋯ ᵢ)
```

However in modern APLs, it is clearly a right fold (*foldr*)

```
      {⍺⍵}/'abcd'
┌→─────────┐
│a ┌→─────┐│
│  │b ┌→─┐││
│  │  │cd│││
│  │  └──┘││
│  └∊─────┘│
└∊∊────────┘
```

I wonder when this change has happened (and what was the motivation)?

Perhaps(?) defining `◌/v` merely as `v₁ ◌ v₂ ◌ ⋯ ◌ vₙ`, which (given APL rules) would parse as *foldr* does make some sense.  On the other hand, implementing efficient *foldl* is rather easier.

Answer (score 5):

*A Programming Language* is from **1962**.

The **1963** paper *Programming Notation in Systems Design* has [the same definition](https://www.jsoftware.com/papers/PNSD1.htm#arrayops).

The **1964** paper *A Common Language
for Hardware, Software, and Applications* [quotes](https://www.jsoftware.com/papers/AFIPS196212.htm) the definition from *A Programming Language*.

At the very end of the **1966** paper *Conventions Governing Order of Evaluation*, Iverson [wrote](https://www.jsoftware.com/papers/EvalOrder.htm):

> 4. In the definition
>
>    `F/x ≡ x1 F x2 F x3 F ... F x⍴x`
>       
>      the right-to-left convention leads to a more useful definition for nonassociative functions `F` than does the left-to-right convention. For example, `-/x` denotes the alternating sum of the components of `x` , whereas in a left-to-right convention it would denote the first component minus the sum of the remaining components. Thus if d is the vector of decimal digits representing the number `n` , then the value of the expression `0=9|+/d` determines the divisibility of `n` by `9` ; in the right-to-left convention, the similar expression `0=11|-/d` determines divisibility by `11` .